# Uploading CSV File to MySQL Server , MYSQL gets terminate every time. Tried with less records as well

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, import-csv

Importing CSV file to MySql Server through MySQl WorkBench . Every it gets terminated. Tried lot of solutions from internet. Still not working

Comment: Any errors? How are you importing -wizard or load data infile, what does your table look like what does the csv look like...

Comment: CSV has one header -> Company name and records of names without any special characters.
MySql Table has 2 columns , 1 is auto increment primary key and other is varchar(2500)